# Data Annotations through web.config in asp.net web forms application

Tags: c#, vb.net, configuration, data-annotations

Assume we have following code 
**c#**

```
  public class Customer
{
  [Required]
  [StringLength(50)]
  public string LastName { get; set; }
[Range(5, 50)]
  public int ReorderLevel { get; set; }

  [Range(typeof(Decimal),"5", "5000")]
  public decimal ListPrice { get; set; }

}
```

or in VB.NET

```
Public Class Customer
    <Required> _
    <StringLength(50)> _
    Public Property LastName() As String
        Get
            Return m_LastName
        End Get
        Set
            m_LastName = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_LastName As String
    <Range(5, 50)> _
    Public Property ReorderLevel() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_ReorderLevel
        End Get
        Set
            m_ReorderLevel = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ReorderLevel As Integer

    <Range(GetType([Decimal]), "5", "5000")> _
    Public Property ListPrice() As Decimal
        Get
            Return m_ListPrice
        End Get
        Set
            m_ListPrice = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ListPrice As Decimal

End Class
```

Is it possible to set the range and required switch on or off from web.config?

This will help user to add/remove validations if business require a change. E.g. need to make one field required or optional.

Or change the range
Cheers

Comment: Have your customer class implement IValidatableObject. Then you can test the condition and apply validation when needed. http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/custom-validation-with.html

Answer (score 0):

You can disable client-side validation by setting the below in your config:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false" />
```